# View criteria in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If a post has a `status` column in the database that has either value `draft` or `published`, how do I define `index` in my controller to show only `status` with `published`? I know I can achieve this using `if-else` in my view, but I wonder if there is a better approach in the controller.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you plan to use often a finder for published posts, you may prefer using a named scope rather than a conditions in you controllers.

*app/models/post.rb* :

```
named_scope :published, :conditions => {:status => 'published'}
```

*app/controllers/posts_controller.rb*

```
@posts = Post.published
```

Comment: This is what I would greatly recommend.

Comment: Works on normal pagination, but when I applied it together with Thinking Sphinx with such: `@shops = @shop_countries.published.collect { |shop_country| shop_country.shop }`, it outputs error: `undefined method `published' for #<ThinkingSphinx::Search:0x106ca3aa8>`.

Comment: I don't know Thinking Sphinx but googling for "Thinking Sphinx and named scope" I get this : http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/scopes.html ...

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. But now it takes another new indexing item in order for TS to work. I will have to determine which is a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

In controller file, modify index method: replace the default `@books = Book.all` with `@books = Book.where(:status => 'published')`