# Simplifying this conditional statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rather complicated (to me) statements to write in Rails. Under the `show.html.erb` of my `Person.rb` which is a user's profile. Each `post` has a `status` column in database with values `draft` or `published`.

```
<% if @posts.blank? %>
  No post.
<% else %>
  <% if @person == current_user %>
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      Post title... (where all published and draft posts are shown)
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <% if post.status == "published" %>
        Post title (where only published posts are shown, draft posts are hide from other users)
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Here's the problem. Suppose `User A` has 1 published post and 1 draft post, it works fine; but if `User B` has 2 draft posts, by right no post will be shown to other users, but I want it to show `No post` like the first 2 lines code.

I tried `named_scope` in my `Post.rb` guided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921673/view-criteria-in-rails-controller), but when I apply .published it just returned me a non-defined error.

Please teach me how to accomplish this. Thank you very much.

Comment: is this rails 3? i think in rails 3 you use scope :published => where(:published => true)

Comment: It's Rails 2.3.8. Sorry for not stating it earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the following:

Create a scope for status on posts.

```
class Post
  named_scope :by_status, lambda { |status| {:conditions => {:status => status} } }
end
```

Move some logic into your controller:

```
class PostsController
  def index
    @person = Person.find(params[:person_id])
    if current_user == @person
      @posts = @person.posts
    else
      @posts = @person.posts.by_status('published')
    end
  end
end
```

Write your view:

```
<% if @posts.empty? %>
  No posts code
<% else %>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    Post title...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This solution should DRY up your code and move more logic into your model.

Comment: Need a closing } in end of named_scope. Works flawlessly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem the quickest way, I'd just exclude draft posts in the first line like this:

```
if (@person == current_user) ? @posts.blank? : @posts.select({ |x| x.status == 'published' }).blank?
```

But that doesn't really simplify what you're doing overall. This is a pretty common problem in views (conditionally doing one thing based on two disparate conditions), and hopefully someone smarter can share a better solution. In the meantime, I offer you this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% @posts.to_a.each do |post|
     if @person == current_user || post.status == 'published' %>
       ...
  <% end 
   end %>
```

The `.to_a` will make `[]` out of a `nil`, so it might just reduce to this...

Comment: Thanks. It works, but with a minor problem. 

`<% @posts.to_a.each do |post| %>
     <% if @person == current_user || post.status == 'published' %>
       Post title...
     <% else %>
       No post code.
     <% end %>
<% end %>`

If I have 2 draft post, 0 published post, it shows 2 "no post code". How can I limit it to just 1?